# Why Would I Be Getting a Gas Estimation Error on Remix? I have plenty of ETH and LINK

Tags: chainlink, solidity-0.8.x

I keep getting this error and can't figure out why. I have 1.4 ETH and 110 LINK in my metamask account. I'm connected to the Kovan testnet. Any help would be much appreciated.

Error:
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
The execution failed due to an exception. Reverted

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.6;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol";

contract CheckingThisOut is ChainlinkClient {
    using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;

    address[] private subaddress;

    address private oracle;
    bytes32 private jobId;
    uint256 private fee;

    constructor() {
        setChainlinkToken(0xa36085F69e2889c224210F603D836748e7dC0088);
        //https://market.link/nodes/323602b9-3831-4f8d-a66b-3fb7531649eb/metrics?start=1640025302&end=1640630102
        //Linkpool
        oracle = 0x56dd6586DB0D08c6Ce7B2f2805af28616E082455;
        //https://market.link/jobs/d3d7cfc4-963e-4bc6-b94d-21bfe8d90aff
        jobId = "c128fbb0175442c8ba828040fdd1a25e";
        // 17 0s = 0.1 LINK
        // 18 0s = 1 LINK
        fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18; // (Varies by network and job)
    }

    /**
     * Create a Chainlink request to retrieve API response, find the target
     * data, then multiply by 1000000000000000000 (to remove decimal places from data).
     */
    function requestSubscriptions() public returns (bytes32 requestId)
    {
        Chainlink.Request memory request = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);

        // Set the URL to perform the GET request on
        request.add("get", "http://1423-104-243-59-126.ngrok.io/");


        request.add("path", "result");

        // Sends the request
        return sendChainlinkRequestTo(oracle, request, fee);
    }


    function fulfill(bytes32 _requestId, address[] memory _subaddress) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
    {
        subaddress = _subaddress;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Wow i figured it out. I spent 5 hours on this and as soon as I posted the question, I watched the same tutorial video again (for the 10th time). I never sent LINK to the deployed contract address. I sent some LINK and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

That's due to insufficient LINK in the deployed contract. It worked after I followed this https://docs.chain.link/docs/fund-your-contract/ and sent 2 LINK to the contract.

Answer (score 0):

@Chris Can you explain how you did that, please? I have .27ETH and 40 LINK in my Kovan Test Net. How do I send Link to the deployed contract address in my code...

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.6.6 <0.9.0;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract FundMe {

    mapping (address => uint256) public addressToAmountFunded;
    
function fund() public payable {
    uint256 minimumUSD = 50 * 10 ** 18;
        require (getConversionRate (msg.value) >= minimumUSD, "You need to spend more ETH!");
            addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    ///msg.sender and msg.value both in every contract call and transaction 
    //msg.sender is the sender and msg. value is how much they sent 
}
function getVersion () public view returns (uint256) {
    AggregatorV3Interface _priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface (0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331);
        return _priceFeed.version();
}
function getPrice () public view returns (uint256) {
    AggregatorV3Interface _priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface (0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331);
        (,int256 answer,,,) = _priceFeed.latestRoundData();
            return uint256 (answer);     
}
function withdraw () payable public {
    msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance);
//this means current contract //whoever called the withdraw function (msg.sender) transfer them the money
}

}
```

Comment: It's been a few months, so I don't really remember. I think I just sent the LINK to the contract address via metamask.